# Apply Tail Recursion for the piece of code in C language?

Tags: c, recursion, tail-recursion

The below is a piece of code which uses recursion to find the product of
     numbers in an array, but i am not getting how to do the same tail recursively
     any suggestions?

```
  int Product(int a[], int i, int n) 
   {
    return (i >= n) ? 1 : a[i] * Product(a, i + 1, n);
   }
```

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: shouldnt the brackets be on the data type and not the the parameter's name ?

Comment: @KevinAvignon, if it was C#, yes. But I was mistaken, the OP has changed the title to mention that it is C.

Answer (score 2):

In its current form, your code isn't tail recursive. The recursive call has to be the last instruction in the function, and in your code the multiplication happens after the recursive call. So you have to change the signature to take an accumulator that will hold the product of the numbers so far:

```
int Product(int a[], int i, int n, int acc) 
{
   return (i >= n) ? 1 : Product(a, i + 1, n, a[i] * acc);
}
```

For the initial call, you should pass 1 as the accumulator value. Since the tail recursive form isn't very convenient to use, you can separate the function into a helper function and another function with the actual implementation:

```
int Product(int a[], int i, int n)
{
    return TailProduct(a, i, n, 1);
}

int TailProduct(int a[], int i, int n, int acc) 
{
   return (i >= n) ? 1 : Product(a, i + 1, n, a[i] * acc);
}
```

Comment: whats the initial value of acc?

Comment: @want2, I edited my answer to mention it. The initial value should be 1, since it's the identity element of multiplication. (for a sum, it would be 0)

Comment: is it same like using goto label and how to do the same using normal iteration?